# Tu proposición vs. tuya proposición

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Yo sé las principales diferencias entre `tu` y `tuyo`, `mi` y `mío`, etc.

```
Esto es tu perro
```

vs

```
Este perro es tuyo
```

Pero no soy seguro del uso de éstos pronombres en siguiente ejemplo:

```
Tu/Tuya proposición es muy interesante
```

Pienso que correcta es la primera opción, pero la segunda también suena bien a mi.
Estaría agradecido por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> De todas las proposiciones recibidas, hemos elegido **la tuya**, porque era la mejor.
>
> <sub>De todas las proposiciones recibidas, hemos elegido **tu proposición**, porque era la mejor.</sub>

En el primer caso **tuya** sustituye a "proposición". Este pronombre debe concordar en género con aquello a lo que sustituye y por eso decimos "tuya" y no "tuyo" (si estuviésemos hablando de un coche diríamos "el **tuyo** es el mejor").

> **Tu** proposición era la mejor.

En este segundo caso no usamos un pronombre. "Tu" no se está refiriendo a "proposición", se está refiriendo a que tú lo tienes. En este caso lo que tienes es un *posesivo* (mi, tu, su,...).

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo entiendo perfectamente :)

Comment: También es posible (aunque no se escucha con tanta frecuencia), «la proposición tuya» (en tal caso, *tuya* sigue siendo adjetivo).